# A very confusing cursor when sculpting

Tags: sculpting

[image: Cursor]

[![When sculpting the cursor has two circles and a cross hair. It is extremely distracting to say the least. I don't even know what the purpose of the double circles are. Is there way to disable this complicated icon or at the very least remove the cross hair?

Comment: When sculpting the send dot will show where it will be mirrored.

Comment: Thanks. What do the inner and outer circles indicate?

Answer (score 2):

The center colored dot snaps to the nearest vertex and also appears on the other side of the model if you have mirroring turned on, as Yohello said. As far as I can tell, the outer circle shows the size of the brush, and the inner circle represents the strength / falloff of the brush, and increases in size as you increase the brush strength.

If you want to disable the cursor entirely, you can uncheck the "cursor" box on the right panel. If you do this, There will only be the normal mouse icon to show the cursor position until you click the mouse / press down the tablet pen to begin sculpting, at which point there will be no cursor.

Or, you could go to the cursor color settings and change the cursor alpha to 0, and a simple crosshair will be shown at all times instead of the dot and circles. Hope this helps!

[image: Cursor options]

Answer (score 1):

1) you have enabled symmetry, the dot on left indicates where the symmetry of your brush will apply.

2) the inner circle indicates strength of the brush. You can change size of your brush by pressing F, when you pres SHIFT+F you can adjust your strength.

[image]
[image]